# Deduce the order of convergence of explicit Euler

Tags: numerical-methods, computational-mathematics, finite-differences, finite-difference-methods

I'm reading the following lecture slides : https://courses.maths.ox.ac.uk/node/view_material/1191. See Page $86$ for my question. In the slides, they are verifying order of convergence of explicit Euler method. We know from theory that explicit Euler is $O(\Delta t + \Delta x^2)$ accurate. I have written MATLAB code that is telling me that two time refinements per refinement in the space coordinate results in the error going down by a factor of roughly four. How can I deduce from this  that explicit Euler is $O(\Delta t + \Delta x^2)$ accurate?

Comment: You can't. You can only confirm that your code is correctly implementing the method, and that the test problem is nice enough that the local truncation errors translate into the global error without order loss. Also give your experiments more breadth, along with $(Δt/4,Δx/2)$ consider the relative error for at least some larger subset of $([1,1/2,1/4]Δt)\times ([2,1,1/2]Δx)$. This should allow to determine the error contributions for the x and t direction separately

Comment: @LutzLehmann  If two time refinements per refinement in the space coordinate results in the error going down by a factor of roughly four, how does it confirm that the code is correctly implementing the method? I'm not clear with this very concept. I think I should have rephrased my question.

Comment: If you have a wrong implementation, the error will be larger or not at all behave according to any order. However, it is not proof of the theoretical order, it is empirical confirmation. On the other hand, a theoretical statement on the order does not tell if the method is practical, that the order can be achieved inside the limitations of the floating-point type. So such tests have a purpose.

Comment: @LutzLehmann So, the fact that error goes down by a factor of $4$ doesn't really matter. The error could go down by a factor of $2 ,3,5,\ldots$ and still the order of convergence is $O(\Delta t + \Delta x^2)$. Of course, considering larger subsets as well as you indicated in the first comment to the post.

Comment: No, that it goes down with a factor of 4 shows that the code is working as to be expected, it is necessary for this form of the error order. And it also shows that the step sizes are inside the working range. To small, and accumulating floating point errors dominate, too large and higher order terms of the error dominate (note that in direction of increasing step sizes, higher order is bad).

Comment: @LutzLehmann Is there any formal justification or proof that error should go down by a factor of $4$?

Comment: In the purely theoretical error, you get leading error terms $a·Δt+b·Δx^2$. If the step sizes are small enough, the contributions of the higher order terms are negligible. Thus going to $(Δt/4,Δx/2)$ reduces the leading error term by $4$. I thought that this was clear from your question text. // For more please transfer the details of the situation from the cited slide to the question.